# Is it possible to share an object from a Python application to a Java application in a GraalVM instance?

Tags: python, java, playwright, graalvm

I have a python application that uses Playwright to navigate to a webpage, extract cookies and store them in a list. What I want is to send this object to a Java application running in the same GraalVM instance so that the Java application can store the cookies in a database.

Here's the Python code:

```
# extractCookies.py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def extract_cookies():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto('https://google.com')
        cookies = page.context.cookies()
        browser.close()
        return cookies

if __name__ == "__main__":
    extracted_cookies = extract_cookies()
```

Is this possible in GraalVM through the Polyglot API or through some other means?

Comment: What did you try? I never used GraalVM but googling for "graalvm polyglot" immediately sent me to [GraalVM's reference manual](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/polyglot-programming/#running-polyglot-applications) which seems to answer your question quite well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do something along those lines:

```
        Context ctx = Context.newBuilder("python").allowAllAccess(true).build();
        
        // Evaluates the script, which creates the extract_cookies Python function at the "top level"
        ctx.eval(Source.newBuilder("python", new File("extractCookies.py")).build());
        
        Value extract_cookies = ctx.getBindings("python").getMember("extract_cookies");
        Value extracted_cookies = extract_cookies.execute();
        
        // Let's say the result is a Python list:
        extracted_cookies.getArrayElement(0); // to get the first element
        extracted_cookies.getArraySize(); // to get the size
        
        // Let's say it is not a list, but can be iterated:
        Value iterator = extracted_cookies.getIterator();
        while (iterator.hasIteratorNextElement()) {
            Value element = iterator.getIteratorNextElement();
            // ...
        }
```